# Screenshot from video in memory without writing video or screenshot to disk

Tags: c#, .net, video, ffmpeg

I'm working on a application which processes a substantial quantity of video files. One of the processing steps involves creating a storyboard of the video contents by taking screenshots at certain points.

Currently we are accomplishing this by writing the video from memory to disk, calling ffmpeg to generate a screenshot at a specified time, reading the screenshot to memory, then deleting both the video and screenshot from disk.

The problem is that this is a substantial number of large disk operations, which are turning into a bottleneck.

Ideally, what I'd like to do is to take the screenshots without ever writing the video or screenshot to disk; The video is contained in memory at the time of processing, and all the videos have been transcoded to the mp4 format.

Is there a way to accomplish this, with or without ffmpeg?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Sort of. :) We ended up using Movie Thumbnailer (http://moviethumbnail.sourceforge.net/), which creates storyboards for videos with pretty good performance. It creates the screenshots with one read-through of the video. It is also possible, apparently, to do the same thing with ffmpeg, but MTN wraps the (rather confusing) ffmpeg functionality nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up solving this with Movie Thumbnailer (http://moviethumbnail.sourceforge.net/), which creates storyboards of videos with one read-through, eliminating most of the seeking time. It can create a storyboard of a blu-ray quality, movie-length video file in under a second.

It is also apparently possible to do this with ffmpeg, but MTN conveniently wraps the (rather confusing) ffmpeg functionality.