# Can you get a video thumbnail using MediaToolkit without reading/writing to disk?

Tags: c#, thumbnails, .net-5, video-thumbnails

I have a video file that's already loaded in memory (an `IFormFile` that's converted to a `byte[]`).

I've been trying to figure out how to take that video and get a thumbnail image from it, without having to read/write to disk.

I found use cases for MediaToolkit and FFmpeg [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177343/generate-video-thumbnail), and Movie Thumbnailer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383282/screenshot-from-video-in-memory-without-writing-video-or-screenshot-to-disk), but from what I can find, those require the video already be saved to disk and have write access to output the thumbnail to a file.

Is there any way I can take either an `IFormFile` or `byte[]` and do something similar to what MediaToolkit is doing while being able to keep the result in memory?

I know a lot of folks are saying `byte[]` isn't the way to go. In that case, I'm more than happy to convert from `IFormFile` to a `Stream`, but I still need a way to do that and keep it in memory.

Comment: I have [posted C# code](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t17050-) that shows how to obtain a snapshot image from video stored in byte array without saving it to disk file, by using the LEADTOOLS multimedia SDK. (Disclosure: I work for the vendor). If you would like to try it, you can download a free evaluation of the SDK from [this page](https://leadtools.com/downloads).

Comment: @AminDodin Your suggestion has a dependency on UWP or WPF (not sure which). This isn't a clean answer and won't help users who aren't using the requisite technology.

Comment: Darn, in the bounty I said "snapshot" I meant to say thumbnail, and I don't know how to change the text...

Answer (score 0):

please try this with `Windows.Media.Editing` should work, not fully tested..

```
    int frameHeight; // you can set the height
    int frameWidth; // ...
    TimeSpan getFrameInTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);


    //Using Windows.Media.Editing get your ImageStream
    var yourClip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(someFile);
    var composition = new MediaComposition();
    // add the section of the video as needed
    composition.Clips.Add(yourClip);

    // Answer - now that your have your imageStream, get the thumbnail
    var yourImageStream = await composition.GetThumbnailAsync(
       getFrameInTime, 
       Convert.ToInt32(frameWidth), 
       Convert.ToInt32(frameHeight), 
       VideoFramePrecision.NearestFrame);
    

    //now create your thumbnail bitmap 
    var yourThumbnailBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(
       Convert.ToInt32(frameWidth),  
       Convert.ToInt32(frameHeight)
    );

    yourThumbnailBitmap.SetSource(yourImageStream);
```

Comment: I do see that you have marked with a comment 'answer' the part working with a stream even though the source was read from a file. I will try to pick up from there to my existing stream and see if that works. What filetypes would that support, or is it specific to a single format? Also, thanks @Transformer for taking the time to dig into this.

Comment: Bummer, this package appears to not be available outside of UWP